# You should not use <Link> outside a <Router> - Import from different folder

Tags: reactjs

My app works, but I want to move my components outside the app folder to have common components etc. When I move them I suddenly get the error  `failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>` Nothing else is changed.

Below is the minimum to get the error.

folder structure

```
- js
  - components
    - Home.js
    - Button.js
  - app
    - src
      - App.js
    - package.json
```

Code

App.js

```
   <BrowserRouter basename={this.basenameUrl()}>
            <div className="app">
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Home.js

```
  render() {
    return <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-10 text-right">
                    <MyButton/>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Button

```
      <Link to="/app/add" className="btn btn btn-info btn-block-no-md">
            Add new
      </Link>
```

Please note, again, that the app works fine when I move the components back into the apps components folder.

Comment: move my components outside the app folder to have common components etc - what is the meaning of this? Please, provide the exact file structure you have. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . The code you posted isn't enough. This could happen if there are dupe router packages.

Comment: what do you mean by: First child? Are you using your App component like this: <App><Child /></App>?

Comment: I made some changes. firstChild is the Home component you can see being used in the route

Comment: Above is not the minimum to get the error.
You have not defined route for path "/app/add" on App.js and many more so please elaborate more for getting error out of your code

Comment: Can you share your full App.js file? including import statements and everything. There might be a problem with your file path in import statements. If you relocate components to another folder, then you will need to redefine the file path.